# Hyper-V: Cannot press any key to boot from installation media

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am running Windows 10 Pro for Workstations (version 1803, 64-bit). I'm trying to create a Windows 7 SP1 virtual machine for running some legacy software.

When the virtual machine starts up, it asks me to press any key to continue booting from the (virtual) DVD drive that contains the installation media. However, I cannot get the virtual machine to acknowledge that I've pressed any keys. I've also tried using the `Type Clipboard Text` feature and `Send Ctrl-Alt-Del`.

Comment: If you click inside window and press a key does it work.  Is the ISO file known to work, has it been used before? Are you using a Gen1 or Gen2 VM?

Comment: Yes, I had clicked inside the window. The ISO ought to work, it was obtained directly from Microsoft. It is a Gen2 VM. See my answer below.

Comment: I've discovered a similar issue with Windows 10 - that I had to be SUPER quick at pressing a key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created this virtual machine with Microsoft's built-in Hyper-V Quick Create tool. That tool creates a Generation 2 virtual machine, which does not seem compatible with Windows 7.

Creating a Generation 1 virtual machine manually from the Hyper-V Manager app worked fine.

Comment: You saved my life.

Answer (score 33):

For Gen 2 VMs, sometimes on first boot, the key presses are not received. So, I usually wait until the first boot times out, and the screen with "Restart" button is displayed, and then tab once or twice to click on that button using the keyboad. After that the keyboard keys are read without issues.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me.

Comment: Works. Amazing long time issue it seems